# insert list of values in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, insert

I am trying to insert a list in SQL. I get a list of two column values from the JOIN query from TableName1 and TableName2. With the count of ProductId, I am inserting ProductId and Quantity into Table3. 
But the insert fails as the ProductId is null. I get two values for ProductId and Quantity from the Join query as below. How to insert this list into Table3 ??

LIST

```
ProductId  Quantity 
56           1
58           2
```

SQL :

```
DECLARE @productid int 
DECLARE @quantity int 

SET @productid  = SELECT A.[ProductId],
A.[Quantity] FROM [TableName1] A
INNER JOIN [TableName2] B
ON A.[OrderId] = B.[OrderId]  WHERE B.[CustomerId] = 1 AND A.[OrderId] = 68


SET @quantity  = SELECT 
A.[Quantity] FROM [TableName1] A
INNER JOIN [TableName2] B
ON A.[OrderId] = B.[OrderId]  WHERE B.[CustomerId] = 1 AND A.[OrderId] = 68


DECLARE @i int = 0
DECLARE @pcount int =  (SELECT COUNT(ProductId) FROM [TableName1] A
INNER JOIN [TableName2] B
ON A.[OrderId] = B.[OrderId]  WHERE B.[CustomerId] = 1 AND
 A.[OrderId] = 68)

WHILE @i <= @pcount 

BEGIN   

    SET @i = @i + 1

    DECLARE @productname nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @productname = (SELECT [ProductName] FROM [TableName4] WHERE [ProductId]= @productid)


    DECLARE @PRate decimal
    SET @PRate =(SELECT [SpecialPrice] FROM [TableName5] 
    WHERE [ProductId]=@productid)


    DECLARE @SPrice decimal
    SET @SPrice = @PRate * @quantity

    INSERT INTO [Table3]
    [ProductId],[ProductName],[Quantity],[Price],[TotalAmount]) 
    VALUES
    (@productid,@productname,@quantity,@PRate,@SPrice)
END
```

How to I pass the productid and quantity in loop to the Table3 for insertion. 
Any mistake in my code while looping ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off writing this as a set based operation:

```
WITH pq AS
(
    SELECT
     A.[ProductId]
    ,A.[Quantity]
    ,D.[ProductName]
    ,E.[SpecialPrice]
    ,E.[SpecialPrice]*A.[Quantity] AS SPrice
    FROM [TableName1] A
    INNER JOIN [TableName2] B
    ON A.[OrderId] = B.[OrderId]
    INNER JOIN [TableName4] D
    ON A.[ProductId] = D.[ProductId]
    INNER JOIN [TableName5] E
    ON A.[ProductId] = D.[ProductId]
    WHERE B.[CustomerId] = 1 
    AND A.[OrderId] = 68
)
INSERT INTO [Table3]
([ProductId]
,[ProductName]
,[Quantity]
,[Price]
,[TotalAmount])
SELECT
 [ProductId]
,[ProductName]
,[Quantity]
,[SpecialPrice]
,SPrice
FROM pq;
```

Comment: Wow. Simple solution. Changed only this line. INNER JOIN [TableName5] E ON A.[ProductId] = E.[ProductId].